# Do we weigh less in the morning?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, weight

A question on [Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/21076/6166) got me thinking, ignoring [weight naturally lost during the night](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/21092/6166), *"Do we weigh less in the morning?"*

During the night, the sun is above us, and the earth below us. Conversely, at night, both the earth and the sun are "below" us. Our mass obviously stays the same, but would there be a greater gravitational pull on us since the added gravity from both the earth and the sun on the other side are acting on us?

Or do we not notice the gravitational pull from the sun, for the same reason astronauts aboard the ISS don't notice the gravitational pull from the earth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are we slightly lighter during the day and slightly heavier at night, owing to the force of the Sun's gravity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121775/)

Comment: @JohnRennie Darn it, I thought I was being creative and had thought up a unique idea.

Comment: "During the night, the sun is above us, and the earth below us." I think you mean: "During the *day,* the sun is above us ..."

Comment: @IQAndreas - There is an effect, but not in the way you think. If the moon wasn't also there, we would weigh most at sunrise and sunset, least at noon and midnight. Read the answers to the linked question.