# Do I weigh less during high tide?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth, moon, tidal-effect

Given weight = mass * gravity do I weight less during high tide and more when tide recedes?

My guess is weight = mass * gravity * gravitational pull of moon factor

Comment: check out Floris's answer to [Are We Slightly Lighter During the Day?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/121918/63055)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are we slightly lighter during the day and slightly heavier at night, owing to the force of the Sun's gravity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121775/)

Comment: @pentane - yes, I thought I had answered this before...

Comment: As a minor note the local tides (rise and fall of the water) may or may not be synchronized with the tidal forcing (the combined tidal forces of the moon and sun).

Comment: @Floris , pentane : i agree. should i delete it ?

Comment: @michael501 - no you can leave a duplicate. Sometimes people will find this question rather than the original (depending on how they phrase their search). Under certain circumstances "the system" will remove duplicates - no need for you to do anything.